# game can be played with multiple words

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am learning Ruby and improving every day. I have question on how I can play a game with multiple words

Below RSPEC test passed because the game is played with one word

```
fit "is lost with a different set of incorrect guesses" do
  guesses = ["ALPHA", "BETA", "GAMMA"]
  input = StringIO.new(guesses.join("\n")) 
  game = Game.new(answers: ["RUBY"], input: input, output: output, 
  max_attempts: 3)

  game.start

  game_output_lines = output.string.split("\n").map(&:strip)

  aggregate_failures do
    expect(game_output_lines.size).to eq 9
    expect(game_output_lines[2]).to eq "The answer is not ALPHA."
    expect(game_output_lines[3]).to eq "Try again. Attempts left: 
    2"
    expect(game_output_lines[4]).to eq "The answer is not BETA."
    expect(game_output_lines[5]).to eq "Try again. Attempts left: 
    1"
    expect(game_output_lines[6]).to eq "The answer is not GAMMA."
    expect(game_output_lines[7]).to eq "You lost."
    expect(game_output_lines[8]).to eq "Your final score: 0/1."
  end
```

Below is the test that is failing because I have to play with multiple words. For clarity sake, once the  "expect(game_output_lines[7]).to eq "You lost." I want to be able to replay the game so that "expect(game_output_lines[8]).to match(/^2/2. Guess a word from an anagram [OMEGA] {5}$/)" below will be possible

```
it "can be played with multiple words" do
  guesses = ["ALPHA", "BETA", "GAMMA", "MEGA", "OMEGA"]
  input = StringIO.new(guesses.join("\n")) 
  game = Game.new(answers: ["DELTA", "OMEGA"], input: input, 
  output: output, 
  max_attempts: 3)

  game.start

  game_output_lines = output.string.split("\n").map(&:strip)

  aggregate_failures do
    expect(game_output_lines.size).to eq 14
    expect(game_output_lines[2]).to eq "The answer is not ALPHA."
    expect(game_output_lines[3]).to eq "Try again. Attempts left: 
    2"
    expect(game_output_lines[4]).to eq "The answer is not BETA."
    expect(game_output_lines[5]).to eq "Try again. Attempts left: 
    1"
    expect(game_output_lines[6]).to eq "The answer is not GAMMA."
    expect(game_output_lines[7]).to eq "You lost."
    expect(game_output_lines[8]).to match(/^2\/2. Guess a word from 
    an anagram [OMEGA]{5}$/)
    expect(game_output_lines[9]).to eq "The answer is not MEGA."
    expect(game_output_lines[10]).to eq "Try again. Attempts left: 
    2"
    expect(game_output_lines[11]).to eq "Correct! The answer is 
    OMEGA."
    expect(game_output_lines[12]).to eq "So far you have correctly 
    guessed 1 out of 2."
    expect(game_output_lines[13]).to eq "Your final score: 1/2."
 end
```

Below is the main code. The code is good for the first test but fails for the second test.

```
class Game
  def initialize(answers:, input: $stdin, output: $stdout, 
    max_attempts: 3)
    @answers = answers
    @correct_answers = 0
    @input = input
    @max_attempts = 3
    @output = output
  end

  def start
    output.puts "Let's play a game. You will have to guess 1 
    anagram."
    output.puts "1/1. Guess a word from an anagram #{answers[-1]}"
    evaluate_user_guesses
  end

  def evaluate_user_guesses
    guess = nil
    current_attempt = 1
    max_attempts_count = 3
    guess_counts = 1
    scores = 1
    while guess != answers[-1] && current_attempt <= max_attempts
      guess = input.gets.to_s.strip
      if guess == answers[-1]
        output.puts "Correct! The answer is #{answers[-1]}."
      else
        output.puts "The answer is not #{guess}."
      end
      if guess == answers[-1]  && current_attempt <= max_attempts
        output.puts "So far you have correctly guessed # 
       {guess_counts} out of # 
        {scores}."
        return output.puts "Your final score: #{guess_counts}/# 
        {scores}."
      elsif guess != answers[-1] && current_attempt < max_attempts
        output.puts "Try again. Attempts left: #{max_attempts_count 
        -= 1}"
      else 
        output.puts "You lost."
      end
      current_attempt += 1
    end
     output.puts "Your final score: #{guess_counts -= 1}/# 
     {scores}."
  end

  private

  attr_reader :answers, :correct_answers, :input, :max_attempts, 
  :output
end
```

How can i make the second test pass?

Thanks

Comment: Your code will not run as is. Please copy and paste what you have published here, get it to run and then edit your question so we can run your code. For example `Anagram` is undefined in `Game` and `output` is a private RSpec method, did you mean to set the `output` kwarg to `$stdout` when you instantiate a game in your tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`answers` is an array which can contain multiple elements, but you only ever take `answers[-1]` into account, i.e. the last element:

```
if guess == answers[-1] # <- compares guess to last element
  output.puts "Correct! The answer is #{answers[-1]}."
```

Instead, you have to compare `guess` to *all* elements in `answers`, e.g. via [`include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#include-3F-method):

```
if answers.include?(guess)
  output.puts "Correct! The answer is #{guess}."
```

In addition, you probably want to [`delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#delete-method) the correct guess from `answers` so the player can't "guess" the same word over and over again:

```
if answers.include?(guess)
  output.puts "Correct! The answer is #{guess}."
  answers.delete(guess)
```

You still have to adjust some other parts of your code, but this sould point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I've been able to sort it out.

Comment: @AdesuyiFisola if it helped you solve the problem, you might want to accept my answer and / or upvote it once you got enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I just did. I am not aware of this before. Thanks for telling me